Two files (excel & pdf) must match the file name using ADF
After using If condition, if the two files are existing, inside true condition, I need to check if those files are exactly the same or matched.

ex. Student_12345.xlsx, Student_12345.pdf -> CORRECT -> proceed to other activites
ex. Student_12345.xlsx, Student_12348.pdf -> INCORRECT -> databricks notebook.

If Condi
I am asking what adf activities to try and expression to achieve this? thank you
I am thinking to use filter activity but idk if it's right.

You can follow below procedure to get your requirement:
Use Get metadata activity to list the files in folder, use binary dataset with folderName datase parameter for folder, create Child items as Feild list then you will get the files list in the folder. Use two filter activities to filter PDF and Excel files. To filter Pdf files pass @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems as items and use @contains(item().name,'.pdf') as condition as shown below:

To filter Excel files pass @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems as items and use @contains(item().name,'.xlsx') as condition as shown below:

After successful filtration, if you have only two files i.e. Student_12345.pdf,Student_12345.xlsx are there in your folder you can use below expression to find filenames are exactly matched in if condition:
@and(
    and(
        equals(length(activity('FilterPDFs').output.value), 1),
        equals(length(activity('FilterExcels').output.value), 1)
    ),
    equals(split(activity('FilterPDFs').output.value[0].name, '.')[0],split(activity('FilterExcels').output.value[0].name, '.')[0])
)


The above expression will check the two filter activities has exactly one file and both the file names are exactly matching or not. If true proceed to other activities or false add databricks notebook according to your requirement. It works as expected:


Thank you so much for this solution. However, how can I put this inside my If Condition 1. In my 1st if condi, I need to check first if those files were existing, if true then check if those file names were matched.

But I need this solution of yours as my back up. :)

Hi @Bhavani, may I ask what are the other adf activity to use instead of If condition to achieve my goal? I cannot use If condition after the 2 filter bcoz they are inside already of If Condition.

@kimchigirl try with filter activity.
